LaTeX ToC list without asociated page number for listed item, in LyX
I am required to list my CV as the last item in my dissertation's table of contents. However, the CV should only be mentioned in the ToC without pointing at the respective page where it would be found on the document. How can I force the CV to appear in the table of contents without a respective page number pointer? E.g. I need something like:
Chapter 1 ......... p.5
Chapter 2 ......... p35
References ........ p 120
CV
I am using LyX, with document class article.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft} % Allows customization of TOC

\begin{document}

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

% Chapters (example)
\section{Chapter 1}
\newpage
\section{Chapter 2}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References} % Add References normally
\section*{References}
\newpage

% Add CV to TOC without page number
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{CV}{\hfill}} % Correctly aligns CV without page number

% Start the CV section without showing it in the document
\section*{CV}

This is the CV section content.

\end{document}


Try \addtocontents{toc}{\string\addvspace{10pt}CV\string\par} instead.

Thanks so much! It worked with John's emendation like a charm.
